# Can't Download PyQt5 on Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm using Pycharm and when i try to download pyqt5 package, I'm getting an error like this.

```
  Failed building wheel for PyQt5-sip
  Running setup.py clean for PyQt5-sip
Failed to build PyQt5-sip
Could not build wheels for PyQt5-sip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: it says requirements already satisfied

Comment: my os is windows

Comment: @eyllanesc python 3.8.1

Comment: @eyllanesc do i need to change my python version?

Comment: execute: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`  end then `python3 -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: It worked thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upgrade pip and then install pyqt5:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
python3 -m pip install pyqt5
```

Comment: @FlyingThunder If the solution does not work for you, it is because your error is probably caused by another error, so I recommend you write a new post explaining your problem and pointing out the characteristics of your environment (OS, python version, etc.)